# replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it, running in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have posted this problem from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4825#issuecomment-153567540)

I am running sharded mongodb in a kubernetes environment, with 3 shards, and 3 instances on each shard. for some reasons, my mongodb instance have been rescheduled to another machine.

the problem is when a mongodb instance have ben rescheduled to another instance, its `replica config` will be invalidated. resulting to this error  below.

```
            > rs.status()
            {
                "state" : 10,
                "stateStr" : "REMOVED",
                "uptime" : 2110,
                "optime" : Timestamp(1448462710, 6),
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-11-25T14:45:10Z"),
                "ok" : 0,
                "errmsg" : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it",
                "code" : 93
            }
            >
```

this is the config

```
            > rs.config().members
            [
                {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "mongodb-shard2-service:27038",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : 0,
                    "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "shard2-slave2-service:27039",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : 0,
                    "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "shard2-slave1-service:27033",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : 0,
                    "votes" : 1
                }
            ]
```

and a sample of  `db.serverStatus()` of a rescheduled mongodb instance

```
            > db.serverStatus()
            {
                "host" : "mongodb-shard2-master-ofgrb",
                "version" : "3.0.7",
                "process" : "mongod",
                "pid" : NumberLong(8),
```

I hope I am making sense.. because, I will be using this in live production very soon.. thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, kubernetes [PetSet](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/) solves this problem. it works like magic

Comment: The webpage doesn't exist anymore. That's why you should quote the information in your answer instead of just dropping a link.

Comment: Just read that "Starting in Kubernetes version 1.5, PetSet has been renamed to StatefulSet."

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to use the old way of setting up mongo (using ReplicationControllers or Deployments instead of PetSet), the problem seems to be in the hostname assignment delay of kubernetes Services. The solution is to add a 10 seconds delay in the container entrypoint (before starting the actual mongo):

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mongo-node1
      image: mongo
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      args: ["sleep 10 && mongod --replSet rs1"]
      ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
      volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage1
          mountPath: /data/db
```

related discussion: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24778

Comment: We saw that intermittently even on some Docker Swarm nodes the mongodb service VIP wasn't available on launch. Adding a 3 second sleep on the entrypoint helped.

Comment: I also encountered this problem when I tried to deploy MongoDB as a StatefulSet. Tried a lot of approaches, but this is the only one that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay. Here is a post that describes in detail how to bring up mongodb:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/mongodb-replica-sets-with-kubernetes-d96606bd9474#.x197hr2ps

One Service and one single-replica ReplicationController per instance is the current approach for a stateful application where each instance needs a stable, predictable identity. With this approach, it is also straightforward to allocate a PersistentVolume for each pod.

Other solutions are possible, such as the sidecar approach shown in that example and the custom seed provider in the Cassandra example, but are a little more complex.

Kubernetes 1.2 will provide a means of setting the hostname (as seen by the container) for each pod. Kubernetes 1.3 will add a new controller to create the instances.

Comment: thanks for the comment. unfortunately, I gave up using k8s in production with regarding to this matter. deployed mongodb's using docker tools instead. until k8s fix the hostnames, deploying mongodb's and other db's like neo4j and likes is not possible for this case. tried all possible solutions, but maintenance and management of mongodbs in k8s is a headache.

Comment: btw, deployed mongodb's/neo4j's in GKE for smaller&dev projects.